# Lipschitz function and Hausdorff distance

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions, hausdorff-distance

I am wondering if we can assume the following if your function $f$ is $K-$lipschitz:
$$\delta(f(A),f(B)) \leq K*\delta(A,B),$$
where we use the definition:
$$\delta(A,B) = \inf\{\epsilon \geq 0\,|\ A \subseteq B_\epsilon \text{ and } B \subseteq A_\epsilon\}.$$
I have troubles to see how one should get this.. Any help would be great!